# Java input file loop

Tags: java, file, loops, input

I have a file which reads

> Office 1
>
> 3
>
> 39 7
>
> 39 7
>
> 39 6.5
>
> Office 2
>
> 2
>
> 19 8
>
> 19 8

This shows which office it is, the next number down is the number of managers in that office then the number of hours each works followed by what they earn per week

I am trying to create a loop so my java file can read the hours then multiply them by the hourly rate then save it as a double then move onto the next office and do the same so I can use the doubles later on in my program, then the loop will end when it gets to the final office I know how to read from the file I am just struggling to get a loop which can do what I specified above

Any help would be much appreciated thanks so much!

EDIT......

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("ExternalData.txt"));
String name;
double employees;
double OfficeRate; 
double OfficeHours; 
double OfficeRate2; 
double OfficeHours2; 
double OfficeRate3; 
double OfficeHours3; 
double OfficeRate4; 
double OfficeHours4; 
name = inFile.nextLine (); 
employees = inFile.nextDouble(); 
OfficeRate = inFile.nextDouble(); 
OfficeHours = inFile.nextDouble();
OfficeRate2 = inFile.nextDouble(); 
OfficeHours2 = inFile.nextDouble();
OfficeRate3 = inFile.nextDouble(); 
OfficeHours3 = inFile.nextDouble();
OfficeRate4 = inFile.nextDouble(); 
OfficeHours4 = inFile.nextDouble();
double Employee1 = OfficeRate * OfficeHours;
double Employee2 = OfficeRate2 * OfficeHours2;
double Employee3 = OfficeRate3 * OfficeHours3;
double Employee4 = OfficeRate4 * OfficeHours4;

double weeklypay = Employee1 + Employee2 + Employee3 + Employee4;
```

Now this works dont get me wrong but it's well to long than it should be surely?

Comment: You say you are struggling to create "a" loop.  Perhaps you need to think about more than one loop.

Comment: i have just been trying a few and nothing has worked, I'm not to sure which type of loop would work best

Comment: you can probably accomplish this in a relatively error-free way, however you may be much better off long term learning how to create structured data files, such as XML for this case. XML would allow you to know exactly where you are in the document's records at any given time, instead of having to assume you are at a certain spot based on number of lines down from the top of the file, etc.

Comment: something like reading your file into a String array, then iterating over the array. Read the file to a String, then do a split, so String.split("\r\n") -- which will return an array, where each element is a line of text from the file.

Comment: @user3036658 Whatever you have tried can you show that? No one is going to write entire code for you. Let us know where you currently stuck and what problem you are facing while accomplishing this.

Comment: i've deleted it, I tried entering it all individually taking each peice of data at a time making it a double or string then multiplying them but it was much to long winded, thats the only one which came close, but I think a loop would be more effective. I'm not after the code to be written for me, I want to leant, a good tutorial would do.

Comment: @user3036658 I will suggest to replicate whatever you have tried and post it here, so SO people can provide their input. In current state your problem look vague and unable to answer.

Comment: i'll edit my post with the code i tried in now

Comment: done, thats just the first office too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224469/java-file-input)

Comment: @user3036658 turbo pointed out to previous question, isnt that sufficient to get your problem solved. Do you still need any help to solve your current issue?

Comment: I am on a placement and this is a task we have to do, we can't use arrays so i was wondering if anyone else had any ideas

Comment: You can't use arrays? I find it hard to believe that you would be told you can't use something that would make your code so much more scalable, useful, and readable..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply and I have ended up writing whole code for you, so understand how this is accomplished.

Anyhow the way you are currently doing is not efficient in case file contains hundreds of office entries.

Just make sure you have **intact** file content as you have shown in your **Post**. If something is **missing** then this following code could get **crash** or give you **unexpected** results.

Here is code for you to accomplish your following requirements. In this case you won't be able to save any **data** from file as you can't use `Arrays`. May be if you have luxury to use `ArrayList` then make use of that to store file data.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Location of file to read
        File file = new File("Your File Path");

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\s+");
            String line;
            String office = null;

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                line = scanner.next();
                if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("Office")) {
                    office = line + scanner.next();
                    // System.out.println(office);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    int empCount = Integer.parseInt(line);

                    double weeklyPay = 0.0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < empCount; i++) {
                        double empPay = Double.parseDouble(scanner.next())
                                * Double.parseDouble(scanner.next());
                        System.out.println("Employee pay: " + empPay);
                        weeklyPay += empPay;
                    }
                    System.out.println("All Employee pay: " + weeklyPay
                            + " for " + office);
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

If you have any questions let me know. Good Luck.